# How can I use individual item from the cells in a column as filter using Power BI?

Tags: powerbi, dax, filtering, powerquery, powerbi-desktop

I have the following data:
Column Name has Ram, Shyam, Hari, Krishna and Ramesh.
Column Fruits has favorite fruits of each person. It can also be multiple fruits.

[image]

I am able to load this data in Power BI using table visualisation, which looks as follows:
[image]

I'd like to use `Fruits` column as filter, and select individual fruit as filter/slicer. However, when I select Fruits as filter, I get combination of fruit in each row as filter. I'd like to get individual fruits as filter e.g., Mango, Banana, Pear, etc.

If I select Mango, then it should show not only the row, which has only Mango as favorite fruit (Hari), but it should also other rows which has Mango and any other fruit as filter (Ram).

[image]

How can I achieve this using Power BI?

I also tried converting the data into individual columns for each fruit.
[image]

But then I can filter only one column at a time.
[image]

How can I filter the table using individual fruit in Power BI?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to reshape your data.

With your data in Power Query as follows:

[image]

Split the fruits column by delimiter into rows.

[image]

Format/trim the column.

[image]

Create a new blank query and open the advance editor and type.

```
let
    Source = Input
in
    Source
```

Input is the name of your first query.

Remove the Name column and then remove duplicates on the Fruits column. Call the query FruitsDimension.

[image]

Close & load and create a relationship between the tables as follows.

[image]

Create a table visual and drag name into it. Create a slicer and drag fruit from the fruit dimension into it.

Create a measure and also drag that to the table.

```
Fruits Measure = CALCULATE(CONCATENATEX(Input, Input[Fruits], ","), REMOVEFILTERS(), VALUES(Input[Name]))
```

If you did everything correct, you will now have a working solution.

[image]

[image]

Comment: Thank you very much! This seems to be working. I have a few questions. 
1. Could you add explanation to the Fruits Measure function? 
2. I also get a Total row in the table at the end with the list of all the fruits. How can I remove this row?
3. Could you suggest any resources for learning Power BI? 
I shall mark this answer as correct.

Comment: 1. The measure is used to recombine all the different fruits that each person has because you split them in the previous steps. 2. You can turn totals off in the format pane. 3. You can learn a lot from youtube. I think excelisfun has some excellent content for beginners.